# How do vertices of a graph form a ring

Tags: graph-theory, ring-theory

An article by I. Beck, JOURNAL OF ALGEBRA 116, 208-226(1988) considers  all the elements of the ring  are vertices of the graph. How do we prove that the vertices of the graph/graphs form a ring? What are the additive and multiplicative operations here? Can a set of the vertices of arbitrarily different graphs also form ring or semiring? 
Edit: the statements of the above cited article goes like this, ' Let $R$ be a commutative ring. We consider $R$ as a simple graph whose vertices are the elements of $R$...

Comment: There is no way for us to answer this without context. At least, you should quote the relevant bits of the article.

Comment: From your first sentence it seems that the article makes a graph from a ring, and not the other way around as you want to. However, there are rings on any number of elements (say, at least two). So in principle, we can make a ring out of the vertices (finite graph assumed), but without any further information this construction is pretty useless.

Answer (score 9):

The second paragraph of the paper states:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. We consider $R$ as a simple graph whose vertices are the elements of $R$, such that two different elements $x$ and $y$ are adjacent iff $xy = 0$.

You ask, "How do we prove that the vertices of the graph/graphs form a ring?" The vertices of the graph do not form a ring; they are merely vertices. The author is not claiming that graphs can be turned into rings; he is starting with a ring and constructing a graph based on its properties.